# PHP datetime field SELECT on today?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I can't get my select statement to filter a datetime column on today:
I only need the rowcount (how many)

```
$u_today = date('Y-m-d');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wds_sec1tasks WHERE due_date = '$u_today'");
$u_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo $u_rows;
```

Do I need to grab the left 10 chars of the datetime to compare? substr(due_date,0,10)?

thanks,
JM

Comment: What type is `due_date` in MySQL? DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP?

Comment: due_date is datetime (I cant change this, not my table). I really only care about the date. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert `due_date` in a `DATE` first by doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM wds_sec1tasks WHERE DATE(due_date) = '$u_today'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`CURRENT_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wds_sec1tasks WHERE due_date = CURRENT_DATE");
```

Comment: hint: `select current_date = now()` ;-)

Comment: For sure, but he'd be stuck with the same problem if he tried :) Also `CURRENT_DATE` is the time as seen on the MySQL server, which might be different than the PHP time (though unlikely and probably not a big deal if it were)